# Combining multiples caption in figures and tables

Tags: tables

I have a LaTeX project in which I want to combine English and Spanish. Specifically, I want all the figures to have the word "Figure" as caption, but I want to use the word "Figura" in specific occasions. How should I do this?

In the same way, I would like to combine "Table" and "Tabla".

Edit: I can't use babel.

Comment: Please post your code, what you tried so far.

Comment: With bable you switch languages.  Note the floats are formatted when they are created.

Answer (score 2):

I finally come up with an easy solution:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat={default},labelsep=space,name={Figure}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat={default},labelsep=space,name={Table}}

% To use "Figura" instead of "Figure"
\newcommand{\figura}{\renewcommand*\figurename{Figura}}

% To use "Tabla" instead of "Table"
\newcommand{\tabla}{\renewcommand*\tablename{Tabla}}
```

With this setup, all figures and tables use the English word by default. To use the Spanish word it is as simple as add `\figura` or `\tabla` before `\caption{...}`.